# Google Geocode Javascript API - How to get coordinates?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I would like Google Maps to convert a user submitted address into map coordinates. I only want these coordinates to be stored in a variable, to be accessed later:

```
function map_search() {
    console.log("search form functional"); // sanity check
    var searchLoc = $('#search_location').val();
    console.log(searchLoc);
    var searchCoords = geocoder.geocode( {'address': searchLoc});
    console.log(searchCoords);

    ...
}
```

I am setting it up like so:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

This works up to the point where `var seachCoords` is defined. In console, it simply prints as `undefined`.

Other Google Maps functions are operating successfully on this page. 
Is my JavaScript wrong, or am I using this geocoder improperly?

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

> The Geocoding service requires a callback method to execute upon retrieval of the geocoder's results. This callback should pass two parameters to hold the results and a status code, in that order.

example:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results); // all results
        console.log(results[0].geometry.location); // "first" location
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
```

NOTE: this is by it's nature **asynchronous**, so don't try to put this in a function that returns `results[0].geometry.location` in a return statement

Comment: OK. I don't want to create a marker, but I think I could try and use this tactic for sending the coordinates through a POST request, which is what I am trying to do. Thanks for the find.

Comment: I posted the exact code from the documentation - I'll edit so as not to confuse the issue

Comment: Thank you :) If I save my variable here, is it supposed to save it for later, or do I need to wrap my POST ajax code inside this function?

Comment: save it in a global, or use a callback, or use a promise - the choice is yours

Comment: Yeah, the asynchronous bit is throwing me off. By the time it saves the variable, the functions that needed it have already failed.

Answer (score -1):

Try this php script:

```
function getCoordinates($address){

$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address); // replace all the white space with "+" sign to match with google search pattern

$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=$address";

$response = file_get_contents($url);

$json = json_decode($response,TRUE); //generate array object from the response from the web

return ($json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].",".$json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']);

}
```

How to call the function in php:

```
echo getCoordinates('740 Story Rd San Jose CA 95122');
Result : 37.328865,-121.8581845
```

Comment: Wow. I've never used PHP before. I should take some time to learn before implementing it.

Comment: PHP is server side - how is this even an answer

Comment: Hah yeah I thought so. I am not using PHP.